# Одинаковое расстояние относительно верха и низа (UI)

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы расстояние где красная стрелка совпадала с зелёным, нужно как-то взять позицию от правой стороны до картинки и поставить его где зелёная стрелка, а то при изменении экранов разный отступ от верха сейчас он выставлен якорями в процентном соотношении от канвас а высота канваса на каждом экране разная и тут вытекает что и процент от той же высоты экрана 1280 будет другой если сравнивать с 2536.

Вообщем сейчас выходит так что на каких-то разрешениях отступ сверху больше чем справа а хочу чтобы было на всех экранах отступ справа ровнялся отступу сверху

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [мануал юнити по работе с фишками RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html). Там много полезного.

А конкретно по вашему вопросу - помимо процентного соотношения вы можете нажать на саму картинку якорей, которая почти сразу под именем класса RectTransform и там будут базовые пресеты, среди которых есть нужный вам - Top - Right.

Так же, другими словами, если оба ваши якоря будут установлены в конкретную точку, то привязка будет осуществляться конкретно к этой точке - Anchors Min(1,1), Max(1,1) даст вам привязку всех координат к верхнему правом углу родителя, а Min(0,0), Max(0,0) соответственно к нижнему левому и т.д.

Comment: Я вот не могу понять а обязательно нужно делать чтобы якоря были по краям объекта?

Comment: @AimonZ., по краям какого объекта? Якоря это привязка вашего объекта к параметрам его родителя.